# Display another layout on button click

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, windows-phone-7

I have a layout MainPage.xaml in which i have images and a button.
On click of button i want another layout Top.xaml to be displayed such that MainPage.xaml becomes invisible.
I am new to Windows phone 7?
Can someone help out?

Comment: possible duplicate of [want to have various layouts in the application ?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332583/want-to-have-various-layouts-in-the-application)

Answer (score 3):

This depends on what you are looking to do.  You can either navigate from MainPage.xaml to Top.xaml using

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Top.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
```

If you just want to switch between layouts (i.e. not navigate to a whole new page) you can implement both layouts in one XAML page and switch between them using VisualStateManager.  Create one state called "Main" and other called "Top" then switch from one to the other as follows:

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(this, "Top", true);
```

It all depends on how you want to layout your code and also how you expect the back button to work.  Using states means you will have to handle the back button yourself.

Comment: How to create different states?

Comment: Use the "States" tab in Expression Blend.  See this for details http://www.silverlight.net/learn/videos/silverlight-videos/add-states-to-a-usercontrol-for-silverlight/
Just be sure that it is visual states that you want and not Navigation.

Comment: Can you explain more as I am not familiar with  the terms : Expression Blend, Visual states

Comment: I am doing this on button click inMAinPage.xaml.cs file:        private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("Top.xaml", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));         

        }                                                                           But navigation is failing.